# Attack mode for DES + ECB

Tags: des, ecb

Given that the plain text(P) and the ciphertext is known, and there's a random string(8 bytes)(S) concatenated to the plain text(P || S), how to go about figuring out the random string. Querying of black box is unlimited.

Comment: So the ciphertext is the ECB encryption of P||S for a 64-bit value of S; the ciphertext C is known; and you want to find S? Are we to assume that the key is unknown? (Otherwise, it's easy...)

Comment: Can you please specify _exactly_ what the black box will be doing to the given input?

Comment: The key will be unknown. And the black box will be encrypting the plaintext ( P || S) with the key to produce the ciphertext.

Comment: For DES another option is to simply brute force DES until you find the key and, therefore, S. Not recommended on a general purpose CPU though, unless you want to heat your room.

Comment: This is actually a well known crypto challenge by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you've let the box encrypt 'AAAAAAAx' for all byte values of x. (It will be the first block of the total output). Then send AAAAAAA and see what the first block is. You know now what last byte is and it's the first one of S. Now you know one byte. Think and iterate.